# Applet Graphic Bug?

Tags: java, multithreading, applet, graphic

I got this really annoying error. It's really hard to explain, but basically whenever my snake tiles (I'm coding the game "Snake") leaves the screen, I set it so it returns to the same y, but the x as 0, as the x = 0 is the leftmost part of the screen...

So yeah, hard to explain. Here's the full code:

Main Class:

```
package com.Code0.Snake.Main;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

import com.Code0.Snake.Listeners.KeyListenerS;
import com.Code0.Snake.Threads.EventS;

public class MainS extends Applet{

//Defining vars.
public final int BOX_HEIGHT = 15;
public final int BOX_WIDTH = 15;
public final int GRID_HEIGHT = 30;
public final int GRID_WIDTH = 30;
public static final int NORTH = 1;
public static final int SOUTH = 2;
public static final int EAST = 3;
public static  final int WEST = 4;
public static final int NONE = 0;
public static int direction;
public LinkedList<Point> snakeParts = new LinkedList<Point>();
public Point itemLocation = new Point();
public Graphics graphics;
int randomX; 
int randomY; 
int runCount = 0;
EventS events = new EventS(this);
KeyListenerS keylistener = new KeyListenerS(this);

//On Initialization
public void init(){
    //Adding "Snakeparts" to the linked list.
    snakeParts.add(new Point(10, 10));
    snakeParts.add(new Point(10, 11));
    snakeParts.add(new Point(10, 12));
    this.addKeyListener(keylistener);
}

//Startup paint method.
public void paint(Graphics paramGraphics){
    graphics = paramGraphics.create();
    this.customInit();
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.drawAll();
}

public void customInit(){
    this.runCount++;
    this.setSize(new Dimension(451,451));
    if(this.runCount == 2){
    Thread eventThread = new Thread(events);
    eventThread.start();
    }
}

//Used to call all draw methods.
public void drawAll(){
    Random random = new Random();

    //Calling all draw methods.
    this.drawGrid(graphics);
    this.drawFruit(graphics,random.nextInt(GRID_WIDTH),random.nextInt(GRID_HEIGHT));
    this.drawSnake(graphics);
}

public void drawGrid(Graphics paramGraphics){
    paramGraphics.drawRect(0,0,BOX_WIDTH * GRID_WIDTH,BOX_HEIGHT * GRID_HEIGHT);

    //Drawing horizontal lines.
    for(int x = BOX_WIDTH; x < BOX_WIDTH * GRID_WIDTH; x+=BOX_WIDTH){
        paramGraphics.drawLine(x,0,x,BOX_HEIGHT * GRID_HEIGHT);
    }
    //Drawing vertical lines.
    for(int y = BOX_HEIGHT; y < BOX_HEIGHT * GRID_HEIGHT; y+=BOX_HEIGHT){
        paramGraphics.drawLine(0, y, GRID_WIDTH * BOX_WIDTH,y);
    }
}

public void drawSnake(Graphics paramGraphics){
    paramGraphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    for(Point point : this.snakeParts){
        paramGraphics.fillRect(point.x * 15, point.y * 15, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
    }
    paramGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public void drawFruit(Graphics paramGraphics, int paramX, int paramY){
    paramGraphics.setColor(Color.RED);
    int tempX = paramX * 15;
    int tempY = paramY * 15;
    paramGraphics.fillOval(tempX, tempY, BOX_WIDTH,BOX_HEIGHT);
    paramGraphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

public void drawEmpty(Graphics paramGraphics, int x, int y){
    paramGraphics.clearRect(x * 15, y * 15, 15, 15);
    this.drawGrid(graphics);
}

}
```

Event Class (run on seperate thread):

```
package com.Code0.Snake.Threads;

import java.awt.Point;

import com.Code0.Snake.Main.MainS;

public class EventS implements Runnable{

MainS main;
int CURRENT_DIRECTION;

public EventS(MainS paramMain){
    this.main = paramMain;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    //Infinite loop checking the game and updating it.
    while(true){
        main.drawGrid(main.graphics);
        Point head;
        Point tail;
        Point finalPoint = new Point();

        switch(MainS.direction){

        //If direction = north
        case(MainS.NORTH): 
            head = main.snakeParts.getFirst();
        finalPoint = new Point(head.x, head.y - 1);
        main.snakeParts.push(finalPoint);
        tail = main.snakeParts.getLast();
        main.snakeParts.remove(tail);
        main.drawSnake(main.graphics);
        main.drawEmpty(main.graphics, tail.x, tail.y);
        break;

        //If direction = south
        case(MainS.SOUTH):

            head = main.snakeParts.getFirst();
        finalPoint = new Point(head.x, head.y + 1);
        main.snakeParts.push(finalPoint);
        tail = main.snakeParts.getLast();
        main.snakeParts.remove(tail);
        main.drawSnake(main.graphics);
        main.drawEmpty(main.graphics, tail.x , tail.y);
        break;

        case(MainS.WEST):
            head = main.snakeParts.getFirst();
        finalPoint = new Point(head.x - 1, head.y);
        main.snakeParts.push(finalPoint);
        tail = main.snakeParts.getLast();
        main.snakeParts.remove(tail);
        main.drawSnake(main.graphics);
        main.drawEmpty(main.graphics, tail.x , tail.y);
        break;

        case(MainS.EAST):
            head = main.snakeParts.getFirst();
        finalPoint = new Point(head.x + 1, head.y);
        main.snakeParts.push(finalPoint);
        tail = main.snakeParts.getLast();
        main.snakeParts.remove(tail);
        main.drawSnake(main.graphics);
        main.drawEmpty(main.graphics, tail.x , tail.y);
        break;

        case(MainS.NONE):
            break;
        }

        if(finalPoint.x > main.GRID_WIDTH){
            int totalSnakeParts = main.snakeParts.size();
            main.snakeParts.clear();
            for(int i = totalSnakeParts; i > 0; i--){
                Point tempPoint = new Point(i - 2, finalPoint.y);
                main.snakeParts.add(tempPoint);
                main.drawGrid(main.graphics);
                System.out.println(tempPoint);
            }   
            main.drawSnake(main.graphics);
        }
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

}
```

KeyListener Class:

```
package com.Code0.Snake.Listeners;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import com.Code0.Snake.Main.MainS;

public class KeyListenerS implements KeyListener{

MainS main;

public KeyListenerS(MainS paramMain){
    this.main = paramMain;
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        if(main.direction == main.SOUTH){
            return;
        }
        main.direction = main.NORTH;
    }
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        if(main.direction == main.NORTH){
            return;
        }
        main.direction = main.SOUTH;
    }
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        if(main.direction == main.EAST){
            return;
        }
        main.direction = main.WEST;
    }
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        if(main.direction == main.WEST){
            return;
        }
        main.direction = main.EAST;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

}

}
```

**EDIT**

Here's the link to what it looks like (the bug):

http://s15.postimg.org/8z62dy7az/Bildschirmfoto_2014_06_03_um_16_47_48.png

Comment: What should it do, and what does it do? It's really unclear. You should add images too...

Comment: Ok, I added a link at the bottom.

Comment: Just a remark: you should not redraw the whole grid inside your loop when the snake goes too far right (does not help for your problem...)

Comment: I'll change that, but it also doesn't help me, right..?

Comment: Is it expected that your algorithm teleports the snake in case it goes out of bounds instead of doing the classical world-wrap? Because the latter can be done in a single line instead of the for loop you have...

Comment: And would also solve your problem instantly...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll try to go through your mistakes one-by-one, but really, this is a huge mess.

1. You save the graphics state and call paint from a separate `Thread`. Now, I'm not sure about applets and AWT, but in Swing that is a *huge* no-no. There is a convenient `repaint()` method available...
2. You do not have any synchronization on `direction`. This means the model can ignore the users commands if it feels like it. Try `volatile`. In fact, having both all variables and your drawing code in one class is fairly bad. MVC is the way to go.
3. You suffer from a large amount of off-by-1 errors. If you don't know what it is - google will help you. Just to name a few places where you have them: `finalPoint.x > main.GRID_WIDTH` will fire one cell too late since the grid starts with 0, `for(int i = totalSnakeParts; i > 0; i--){Point tempPoint = new Point(i - 2, finalPoint.y);` means the first point is in a negative coordinate (when i == 1).
4. In your border checking logic you reset the position of all the snake points, *yet you do not paint empty squares on the previous positions*. You do that when processing a move, why aren't you doing it now? That is the residual squares you have left on the right.
5. Your border checks are doing something strange anyway. What they do is straighten out the snake and teleport it to the left edge *completely* instead of just moving the head there. It *looks* the same while the snake is only 3 squares long because of a combination of bugs in number 3, but will be apparent with a longer one (Try it!). A classic approach would be to simply set the x coordinate of the head to 0, instead of resetting everything. That will also make number 4 obsolete, since you won't have to repaint the remainders at all (there won't be any, snake doesn't teleport).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't help my original problem.

Comment: Which is? As I understood your original problem was the green square left on the right.

Comment: @Code0 If it doesn't solve your problem then that isn't Ordus' fault.  You need to do the work and take your problem and try to compose it down to a simple to understand problem to answer.  Ordus did more than I would have to address your various problems.  Pasting all your code for someone to parse and understand decreases the likelihood anyone would want to answer.

Comment: Yes Ordous. I tried your fixes, but it's still there.

Comment: @Code0 Note that I have not pasted a single character of *fixes*. I do not know what exactly did you do to fix the **problems** I have outlined, and whether what you did was correct or not and did it help or not.